# Past Continuous with the Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect, syntax

Could someone help me to fix a sentence? I’d like to say:

> I was going to Italy before the war have come into my country.

I’m not sure that it’s correct. I’d like to use Present Perfect because it means that the war still continues.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say, this sentences says you went to Italy before the war came to your country.

Comment: Possibly, the OP meant to say: “I was **about** to go to Italy when war **broke out** in my country.” This is because learners are often told that "going to" expresses intention in the future.

Answer (score 1):

What you write is ungrammatical. Moreover, it's not clear how to correct it because it isn't clear what you mean.

"I was going to Italy":  Do you mean that "In the past you had started a journey to Italy, but it wasn't completed."  Or do you mean "I was planning a trip to Italy, but cancelled it. I.e.  'I was going to go to Italy'."

The present perfect usually refers to events that are completely in the past, but have an effect on the present.  Your construction of the present perfect is wrong.  It must be "The war has come to my country".  However in this phrase "before ..." you are referencing a past time, so you must use a past tense.  You must say "before the war came to my country".

So I think your sentence should be:

> I was planning to go to Italy before the war came to my country.

Or perhaps

> I went to Italy before the war came to my country.

It might be better to name the country, otherwise it is ambiguous to anyone who doesn't know what country you are from. Similarly it might be better to say which war you are talking about.

Comment: "In the past you had started a journey to Italy, but it wasn't completed" why not started instead of had started is it to emphasize the not completed journey or are  there any other reasons to use past perfect. It is obvious that the journey began before it was completed